# Finding all Strings of Length

Tags: java, string, recursion

Given a class Password of all the passwords that can be written with only the lowercase letters of the English alphabet, I'd like to write an algorithm which recursively finds a password, by going over all of the possible passwords of the same length.

The class Password has a method `public boolean isPassword(String st)`, which compares between a given password p and the string st and returns the boolean value of whether or not they're equal.

Let's call this method `public static String findPassword(Password p, int length)`.

My idea was to do this in two recursive calls - one that goes on the length of p, and continuously adds characters from the alphabet with the method `charAt(i)` on the string `alphabet="abcd.....z"` until it gets a string at the same length as p (meaning length).

The second recursive call will go on the letters of the alphabet creating new strings by changing each time the letter that it adds to the previous string. For instance, given a string `st` of length `L`, we'll first add the letter a, then the letter b, and so on until we get to z, to move from strings of length `L` to length `L+1`.

My problem at the moment is translating some of these ideas into code, and I'd like to do this without any for loops.

Comment: You should show an example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I find it a little difficult to exactly understand what your function is supposed to do. You also say "compare" in your title but nowhere in your actual question. Are you trying to generate all strings of length n containing every permutation of the alphabet?

Comment: Regarding your edit, if you don't know what input your program will take and what it should output, then how will you know what you are doing and when you will be done, coz you don't know what the output should be? This makes no sense. Think again ;-)

Comment: By example output we mean: What should the function return for example when `n=3`. You say: "which creates all of the strings of length n with letters the alphabet as described" so you want to output a set of strings? only one string? Also, I can't seem to find the `as described` part

Comment: You do realize that you'll get a *LOT* of output, right? Number of strings is `26^n`, so `676` for `n=2`, `17,576` for `n=3`, `456,976` for `n=4`, `11,881,376` for `n=5`, and it gets progressively worse from there.

Comment: Could you show an example of expected output for a smaller set of input data, for example `alphabet = "abcd"` and `n=2` ? The question is vague, I can't get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did it as simple `for` loops you'd do this:

```
// For n=1
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    System.out.println(alphabet.substring(i, i + 1));

// For n=2
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        System.out.println(alphabet.substring(i, i + 1) +
                           alphabet.substring(j, j + 1));

// For n=3
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
            System.out.println(alphabet.substring(i, i + 1) +
                               alphabet.substring(j, j + 1) +
                               alphabet.substring(k, k + 1));
```

And so on. That would generate the following for `n=3`:

```
aaa
aab
aac
...
aaz
aba
...
zzz
```

Now, since you can't hardcode number of nested loops for dynamic values of `n`, you use recursion, as you said, but only one recursive call as you progress from `1` to `n`.

This means the recursive method need to receive two parameters: The string so far, and the number of letter left to add.

When in the deepest recursive call, i.e. when no more letters needs to be added, print the result.

Here is pseudo-code:

```
method(String textSoFar, int lettersLeft) {
    if (lettersLeft == 0)
        print textSoFar
    else
        for each letter in alphabet:
            method(textSoFar + letter, lettersLeft - 1)
}
```

You initiate the recursion by calling `method("", n)`.

Remember, you can't return the strings, because you'll build lots of strings for increasing values of `n`:

- 26 strings for `n=1`
- 676 strings for `n=2`
- 17,576 strings for `n=3`
- 456,976 strings for `n=4`
- 11,881,376 strings for `n=5`
- and progressively worse...

Comment: One question - is there a way to change to for loop in the else to recursion, without using 26 different recursions?

Comment: "for each letter in alphabet" *is* a `for` loop.